# JS sort object by "x" in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have been working on a small social photo sharing site for my family photos (as we want to have complete control over the images, local hosting is best). I have developed it working perfectly and want to add functionality.

right now all my images are pulled from MySQL: ROW -> object objects into array -> PHP -> JS array. the array looks like

var array = [{'key' = '1', 'title' = 'title', 'source' = 'path/to/image', 'album' = 'album}, ..]

inside the album tag it could have different album names and want to re-sort the array bases on the albums, I have not thought of a way that works.

Comment: is it a json string ?

Comment: @Andy That question is about sorting the properties in a single object, not sorting an array of objects.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript

Comment: Yeah. I noticed. Knew there was a duplicate somewhere tho.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)**

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.album < b.album;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var array =  [
{'key' :  '1', 'title' :  'title', 'source' :  'path/to/image', 'album' :  'album1'},
{'key' :  '1', 'title' :  'title', 'source' :  'path/to/image', 'album' :  'album2'},
{'key' :  '1', 'title' :  'title', 'source' :  'path/to/image', 'album' :  'album3'},
{'key' :  '1', 'title' :  'title', 'source' :  'path/to/image', 'album' :  'album6'},
{'key' :  '1', 'title' :  'title', 'source' :  'path/to/image', 'album' :  'album5'},
{'key' :  '1', 'title' :  'title', 'source' :  'path/to/image', 'album' :  'album7'},
{'key' :  '1', 'title' :  'title', 'source' :  'path/to/image', 'album' :  'album6'}
];

array.sort(function(a,b){ return a.album > b.album;} );

console.log(array);
```

http://jsbin.com/xefujehe/1/

Answer (score 1):

Check out the docs on MDN for [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

This method takes a comparison function. Here's an example:

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion)
     return -1;
  if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion)
     return 1;
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
}
```

Here's how you'd sort on the album name:

```
var albums = [
{
    key: 110000,
    album: 'Starry nights'
}, {
    key: 100,
    album: 'Zebra kills Zebra'
}, {
    key: 1,
    album: 'Alfred Hitcock Presents'
}, {
    key: 50,
    album: 'baby whales'
}];

albums.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.album === b.album ? 0 : a.album > b.album;
});

console.log(albums);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jimschubert/d27Qt/).

Be aware while sorting that all [capital letters come before all lowercase letters](http://www.ascii-code.com/)